# MYSQL Time Interval and Sum of Data according to the interval

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table which will log all the data based on one minute interval. Now I want to retrieve the records such that, if the time interval is given 2 minutes it should add the complete records with 2 minutes interval and show on screen..
Suppose the Table is:

### Date      |  Time  |   Data

20-11-2011| 9:00   |    2

20-11-2011| 9:01   |    3

20-11-2011| 9:02   |    6

20-11-2011| 9:03   |    2

20-11-2011| 9:04   |    1

20-11-2011| 9:05   |    4

20-11-2011| 9:06   |    4

So, if the start date is selected as 20-11-2011 and start time as 9:01 and interval as 2 minutes, then the table should be:

### Date      |  Time  |   Data

20-11-2011| 9:01   |    9

20-11-2011| 9:03   |    3

20-11-2011| 9:05   |    8

Kindly help me with this, I'm new to mysql and php

Here: Time is a Timestamp type..

Comment: @zerkms: it seems the time is hh:mm only.

Comment: @Kangka: I've asked about mysql data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(`data`), MIN(`time)
FROM tblname
WHERE `time` >= '9:01' AND `date` = '2011-11'20
GROUP BY FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(`time`) - TIME_TO_SEC('9:01')) / 60 / 2)
```

Comment: thank you, however when i enter the query it is showing the complete total of the table with the selected start time, it s not showing the intervals..like
Date | Time | Data

20-11-2011| 9:01 | 9

20-11-2011| 9:03 | 3

20-11-2011| 9:05 | 8

Comment: @Vishal Kumar Verma: updated query a little. Is it better now?

Comment: still the same, it is just showing one row with the total, and moreover its not checking the time..It is showing the total based on only the dates.

Comment: @Vishal Kumar Verma: I don't get what you said. The query works as you asked in the question

Comment: Nope, I don't have time to help in that way. I've given a query that should work like you asked. Your work now is to get how it works and change it to satisfy your expectations